# Javascript closure overwrite function expression

Tags: javascript, closures

I try to figure out, how closure works, this is my example

```
function func1(func) {
    return function(summand) {
        return func() + summand;
    }
}

var func2 = function() {
    return 3;
}

var func3 = func1(func2);
var value = func3(4);

alert(value);

var func2 = function() {
    return 100;
}

var newValue = func3(100);
alert(newValue);
```

First of all let breaks down the code. I write a function that expected as parameter a function and it will return a function.

```
function func1(func) {
    return function(summand) {
        return func() + summand;
    }
}
```

Then i defined the parameter function func2 in expression form

```
var func2 = function() {
    return 3;
}
```

then call func1 and give func2 as pamerater. As result i have got a function back

```
var func3 = func1(func2);
```

then i execute function and pass 4 as parameter argument

```
var value = func3(4);
```

as result i've got 7. Then i overwrite func2 and return 100

```
var func2 = function() {
    return 100;
}
```

then call func3 again and pass as parameter value 100.

```
var newValue = func3(100);
```

as result i've got 103. The first function that i defined(that return a function and takes function as parameter), will still used the first version of func2. This the power of closure, i know it.
But look at the following code, when i define func2 as function declaration not as expression, then func2 will overwrite

```
function func1(func) {
    return function(summand) {
        return func() + summand;
    }
}

function func2() {
    return 3;
}

var func3 = func1(func2);
var value = func3(4);

alert(value);

function func2() {
    return 100;
}

var newValue = func3(100);
alert(newValue);
```

The first value is 104 and second is 200.
My question is, why when i use function declaration it will overwrite the old function, in this example is func2. But when i use function expression it will keep the reference to old func2.
It that because of function hoisting?

Comment: Related: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* because of hoisting. Using the [`function` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffunction) rather than the [`function` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ffunction) causes the function `func2` to get hoisted to the top of the scope. You are overwriting `func2` before any code in the scope gets executed.

because of hoisting you code actually looks like this:

```
function func1(func) {
    return function(summand) {
        return func() + summand;
    }
}

function func2() {
    return 3;
}

// Hoisted!!! Overwriting the previous func2 definition.
function func2() {
    return 100;
}

var func3 = func1(func2);
var value = func3(4);

alert(value);

var newValue = func3(100);
alert(newValue);
```

Inside `func1`, `func` is a stable reference to the function that it was passed... It's just that you are passing the `return 100;` version before you think you are.

Comment: `function` is not an operator.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed in MDN. Will move outside of /operators/ later.

Answer (score 4):

This is not because of closures.

Just like you figured out - this issue is because of **function hoisting**.

You can think of function declarations as "moved up" to the start of the current scope.

```
var f2 = function(){
    return 50;
}
function f2(){
    return 100;
}
```

In this case, f2 is 50 because it gets parsed in a way that's similar to:

```
var f2 = function(){
    return 100;
}
var f2 = function(){
    return 50;
}
```

Because of hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `function foo() { ... }` style, you are defining a function with the name `foo`. When you use the `var foo = function() { ... }` style, you are declaring a variable `foo` (which will be hoisted), and assigning it the anonymous function as its value.

It is ok to write

```
var a;
a = 2;
// ...stuff...
a = 3;
```

and we expect the value to be 3. So it is here, hoisting makes this like:

```
var func2;
func2 = function() { .. some stuff.. };
// ...stuff...
func2 = function() { .. some other stuff .. };
```

By comparison, I think if you define the functions, it will just take the one or other function definition in the initial parse.